# Why does GitHub not upload all of my files?

Tags: github

I have an existing project and I want to upload it to my GitHub so others can see it. I've created a new repo and uploaded the folder with the project. However, it doesn't upload all of the files (50/56):

[image]

The project seems to work after downloading it from the repo. Could someone explain it to me? Is there anything I should fix?

Comment: The screenshot suggests an undocumented limit: https://help.github.com/en/articles/adding-a-file-to-a-repository. For this purpose I would recommend you learn the basic essentials of Git or do a partial upload.

Comment: @bitoiu that limit looks documented to me. :)

Comment: @bitoiu the project takes up 3MB of space. According to the docs, it should upload flawlessly.

Comment: Can you link the repo on GitHub and take a screenshot of the file structure on your computer?

Comment: @gogolon, I didn't say the limit was on size, I said undocumented limit, in this case I implied number of files.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using the command line:

1. [Install git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git) (first check if you have it by typing `git` in terminal)
2. [Configure git](https://help.github.com/en/articles/setting-your-username-in-git)
3. [Push to GitHub](https://help.github.com/en/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line) from terminal:

```sh
$ cd $PATH_TO_FOLDER
$ git init
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "First commit"
$ git remote add origin $LINK_TO_GITHUB_REPO
$ git push -u origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

GitHub does not accept photos or package folders like nodejs or Next that are related to Next packages. You must remove this folder before using GitHub.